# How to do "legacy" ZIP compression with 7zip?

Tags: zip, 7-zip, winzip

We have an old application that requires zip files to be "legacy" format. I would really love to get rid of the adware ridden WinZip and use 7zip. However, I don't know which compression options and such equal out to "legacy".

How to do it?

For reference the compression methods I have to choose from are

1. Deflate
2. Deflate64
3. BZip2
4. LZMA
5. PPMd

Or does which compression method I use even matter? Would it all end up going in as a "legacy" zip file anyway?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using that doesn't have native ZIP support?

Comment: @digi it's an old(circa early 2000s or possibly late 90s) ZIP decompression library used within a program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Legacy zip compression is akin to the **Deflate** method in 7-zip, and will offer the most compatibility between different compression software.

From the [**Winzip KB**](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/177/):

> **.Zip Legacy compression (maximum compatibility):**
>
> The Legacy (Zip 2.0)
>   compression option uses a traditional data compression algorithm,
>   known as deflate, that is supported by all versions of WinZip and
>   virtually all other Zip file utilities. The deflate method is
>   generally considered to be a good all-purpose compression algorithm
>   for most types of files. .Zip: Legacy compression is your best choice
>   when your mail recipient's Zip utility is unknown or known to use
>   older technology. WinZip and WinZip Courier actually use the highest
>   available compression setting for the deflate method or maximum
>   deflate. This way you get the smallest, compatible Zip files possible.

Comment: If the archive extension is .ZIP then specifying the Deflate method is sufficient to get legacy compression. However if the extension is not .ZIP, it seems the command-line 7z.exe defaults _Type of archive_ to -t7z and so -tzip must be specified instead (or in addition).

Comment: "If -t{archive_type} switch is not specified, 7-Zip uses extension of archive filename to detect the type of archive. If you create new archive, -t{archive_type} switch is not specified and there is no extension of archive, 7-Zip will create .7z archive." https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/type.htm